# Check if the first or second condition exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little problem selecting queries, namely when I want to check the first condition with the code below

```
select * from VL_Faktura_Queue where FAK_KundenNr=127849  AND (FAK_BoMatNr LIKE '%verk%' AND FAK_VerrechnetBis ='0001-01-01')
```

, it shows me one position, but when I add a condition where I want to check if there is a `FAK_KundenNr` with `FAK_BomatNr LIKE '% Verk%' OR FAK_BoMatNr Like 'Zus%'` also throws me different values that do not fall under `FAK_KundenNr = 127849`, as I can easily check that it returns my values for this `KundenNr`, where there is 1 OR 2 condition.

this is my query:

```
select * from VL_Faktura_Queue where FAK_KundenNr=127849 
AND (FAK_BoMatNr LIKE '%verk%' AND FAK_VerrechnetBis ='0001-01-01') --this would be the first condition 
or FAK_BoMatNr like 'Zus%' --and this the second condition
```

This is the individual selection I should get but in one query at the end

[image]

so my question is how can i get in one query select from these two query from the picture, thanks everyone for the help

Comment: select * from VL_Faktura_Queue where FAK_KundenNr=32217  AND (FAK_BoMatNr LIKE '%verk%'  or FAK_BoMatNr like 'Zus%') AND FAK_VerrechnetBis ='0001-01-01')

Comment: @PoojaKhokhani thanks for the reply but it's not a good solution

Comment: `select * from VL_Faktura_Queue where FAK_KundenNr=32217 AND (FAK_BoMatNr LIKE '%verk%' AND FAK_VerrechnetBis ='0001-01-01') or (FAK_BoMatNr like 'Zus%' AND FAK_VerrechnetBis ='0001-01-01')`

Comment: @PoojaKhokhani yes but in the second condition i want to have no check for FAK_VerrechnetBis, but only if FAK_BoMatNr is like 'Zus%'

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are not sufficient. `AND` has precedence over `OR`, so you have `FAK_KundenNr = 127849 AND (<first condition)>` OR `FAK_BoMatNr like 'Zus%'`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM VL_Faktura_Queue 
WHERE FAK_KundenNr = 127849 
AND
(
  (FAK_BoMatNr LIKE '%verk%' AND FAK_VerrechnetBis = '0001-01-01')
 or 
  FAK_BoMatNr LIKE 'Zus%'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your requirement, you need to combine the "AND" operator with other logical "OR" operator.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM VL_Faktura_Queue
    WHERE 
        (
          (   FAK_BoMatNr LIKE '%verk%' 
          AND FAK_VerrechnetBis = '0001-01-01'
          )  -- 1st Condition
          or 
          (FAK_BoMatNr LIKE 'Zus%')  -- 2nd Condition
        )
    AND FAK_KundenNr = 127849;
```

Please check if this solution is working for you.